# How can I scrape the contents inside the 'sorting_1' class with Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been given a project to make covid tracker. I decided to scrape some elements through the site (https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/). I'm very new to python so decided to go with BeautifulSoup. I was able to **scrape** the basic elements, like the total cases, active cases and so on. However, whenever I try to grab the country names or the numbers, it returns an empty list. Even though there exists a class 'sorting_1', it still returns an empty list. Could someone guide me where am I going wrong?

This is something which I am trying to grab:

```
<td style="font-weight: bold; text-align:right" class="sorting_1">4,918,420</td>
```

Here is my current code:

```
import requests
import bs4

#making a request and a soup
res = requests.get('https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

#scraping starts here
total_cases = soup.select('.maincounter-number')[0].text
total_deaths = soup.select('.maincounter-number')[1].text
total_recovered = soup.select('.maincounter-number')[2].text

active_cases = soup.select('.number-table-main')[0].text

country_cases = soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'sorting_1'})
```

Comment: A large part of the data is loaded by JS, you only get an almost empty shell when dowloading the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get `sorting_1` class because it not present in page source.
You have found all rows from the table and then read information from the required columns.

So, to get total cases for each country, you can use following code:

```py
import requests
import bs4

res = requests.get('https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

country_cases = soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'sorting_1'})
rows = soup.select('table#main_table_countries_today tr')
for row in rows[8:18]:
    tds = row.find_all('td')
    print(tds[1].text.strip(), '=',  tds[2].text.strip())
```

Comment: This worked like a charm!! I'll experiment with the code further and make something great. Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

Looking at their website, it seems that the `sorting_X` classes are added by javascript, so they don't exist in the raw html.

The table does exist, however, so i'd advise to loop over the table rows similar to this:

```
table_rows = soup.find("table", id="main_table_countries_today").find_all("tr")
for row in table_rows:
    
    name = "unknown"
    # Find country name
    for td in row.find_all("td"):
        if td.find("mt_a"): # This kind of link apparently only exists in the "name" column
            name = td.find("a").text

    # Do some more scraping
```

Warning, i didn't work with soup for a while so this may not be 100% correct. You get the idea.

Comment: Thank You! I got the gist of it from your and other answers' code. Basically, I need to check for the rows. Got the code working, onto experimenting further :)